# Neo4j and relationships creation: bad performance

Tags: database, performance, database-design, graph, neo4j

Hello and thanks in advance for your assistance.

I'm using **Neo4j** (**ver. 3.2.1**, on *Windows 10*) to import 2 CSV files and create a graph between different data with a field in common, as usual.

The first import produce **1 millions** of nodes (*Label_1*), the second import **100000** nodes (*Label_2*).

I've already imported the files and create the nodes successfully; I've tried to connect nodes with a simple query but it's **too slow**, ~100 relationships per minute:

```
MATCH (c:Label_1) WITH c,
c.label_1_key AS currentid
MATCH (g:Label_2) 
WHERE g.label_2_key = currentid
CREATE (g)-[:rel]->(c);
```

Creating 2 **indexes** (one on *label_1_key* and the other on *label_2_key*) doesn't seem to improve performance.

What is the best way to **speed-up** the relationships creation phase?

(I'm working on a notebook with Intel i3 1.9 Ghz and 8GB RAM, if these info can help)

Comment: does this query work / complete? how long is it taking?

Comment: Yes, it works. I've stopped the process after 7 hours (because I decided to search better solutions ... and ask help here ^^")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

1) Create unique indexes :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (l1:Label_1) ASSERT l1.label_1_key IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (l2:Label_2) ASSERT l2.label_2_key IS UNIQUE;
```

2) Load the CSVs to create the nodes (I'm assuming from your explanation it is two separate files and thus two different loads). Will be slightly slower because of the indexes but should still be pretty fast.

3) Use the second file (the smallest) to do one more LOAD CSV.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///second_file.csv" as line
MATCH (l1:Label1 {label_1_key: line.whatevertheheaderofthekeyis})
MATCH (l2:Label2 {label_2_key: line.whatevertheheaderofthekeyis})
MERGE (l1)-[:REL]->(l2);
```

Since you only have 100000 relations to create (again, an assumption made from your explanation), that should be pretty fast.